# Python Flask, UPDATE TABLE

Tags: python, flask, mysql-python

I am writing this message regarding a problem i have, I cant find the error but somehow my table wont update its just keep refreshing same page.

I have following problem that my mysql table wont update from this field 
Python code:

```
@app.route('/edit_item/<string:itemno>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@is_logged_in
def edit_item(itemno):
    #Create cursor
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    #get item by itemno
    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemno = %s", [itemno])
    item = cur.fetchone()
    cur.close()

    #Get form
    form = ItemForm(request.form)
    #Populate item form fields
    form.title.data = item['title']
    form.body.data = item['body']
    form.unit.data = item['unit']
    form.price.data = item['price']

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        title = request.form['title']
        body = request.form['body']
        unit = request.form['unit']
        price = request.form['price']

        #Create Cursor
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        app.logger.info(title)
        #Execute
        cur.execute("UPDATE items SET title = %s, body = %s, unit = %s, price = %s, WHERE itemno = %s", (title, body, unit, price, itemno))
        #commit DB
        mysql.connection.commit()

        #close connection
        cur.close()

        flash('Item Updated', 'succes')
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    return render_template('edit_item.html', form=form)
```

HTML code:
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

```
{% block body %}
  <h1>Edit Item</h1>
  {% from "includes/_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
  <form method="POST" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ render_field(form.title, class_="form-control") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ render_field(form.body, class_="form-control", id="editor") }}
    </div>   
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ render_field(form.unit, class_="form-control") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ render_field(form.price, class_="form-control") }}
    </div>
    <p><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I hope someone can help me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: do you get into `edit_item(itemno)` func? i think you miss the `itemno` in the form action

Comment: i am not sure what you mean, i get into the edit_item(itemno) i get the information as well in the form but what do you mean by action in the form ?

Comment: can you confirm that the line `app.logger.info(title)` is executed and the title is printed?

Comment: Any solution to this yet? I'm experiencing almost the same thing though.